# How to remove '-' from the array number elements run through this function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function below to sum "columns" of a 2D Array, but some elements contain `'-'` and I haven't been able to handle it:

I've tried `Number(num)` or `typeof num === 'number'`, but still...

```js
const arr = [
   ['-', 2, 21],
   [1, '-', 4, 54],
   [5, 2, 2],
   [11, 5, 3, 1]
];

 const sumArray = (array) => {
   const newArray = [];
   array.forEach(sub => {
      sub.forEach((num, index) => {
         if(newArray[index]){
            newArray[index] += num;
         }else{
            newArray[index] = num;
         }
      });
   });
   return newArray;
}
console.log(sumArray(arr))
```

Comment: Running your code generates an error at the "-" in the second line in the first element of the first array. That should be a string? If yes, please, edit the question :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try:

```js
const arr = [
  ['-', 2, 21],
  [1, '-', 4, 54],
  [5, 2, 2],
  [11, 5, 3, 1]
];

const sumArray = (array) => {
  const newArray = [];
  array.forEach(sub => {
    sub.forEach((num, index) => {
      if (typeof num == 'number') {
        if (newArray[index]) {
          newArray[index] += num;
        } else {
          newArray[index] = num;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  return newArray;
}
console.log(sumArray(arr))
```

Here's a more concise solution:

```js
const arr = [
  ['-', 2, 21],
  [1, '-', 4, 54],
  [5, 2, 2],
  [11, 5, 3, 1]
];

const result = arr.map((e, i) => arr.reduce((a, c) => (typeof c[i] == 'number' ? a + c[i] : a), 0))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @onit I've also added a more concise solution which uses `map` & `reduce` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` and `reduce` to achieve this as well.

```js
const arr = [
  ['-', 2, 21],
  [1, '-', 4, 54],
  [5, 2, 2],
  [11, 5, 3, 1],
];

const sums = arr.map((sub) =>
  sub.reduce((previous, current) => {
    // check here that the value is a number
    if (typeof current === 'number') {
      return previous + current;
    }

    return previous;
  }, 0)
);

console.log(sums);

// returns [23, 59, 9, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about the approach using `reduce()`

Comment: This isn't what OP is trying to do though. This sums the values horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score -4):

Using splice() would help remove the - from the array

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I guess folks closed it because it usually require the answer to be more structure, somehow like the question. This is so as to keep the good quality of the community

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).